# Don't display field of form if action is edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have rails form that renders partial with fields list to create new user. Those fields I am also using to render edit form. I wonder if it is possible not to show specific field (i.e. department) on the edit form, because I don't want to give users option to change the department?

Answer (score 15):

You can use **persisted?** method to ensure that it is not a new record that will be inserted or even use **new_record?** method which will return true if the record is not persisted in your database "New record".
ex ::

```
<%= f.text_field :department if @user.persisted? %>
 or 
<%= f.text_field :department unless @user.new_record? %>
```

one more way is to check about the action itself which also gives you control on the controller if you render the partial from different view and you want to limit it to specific controller, these are stored in ::

```
params[:controller] -->> contains the name of the controller ex. UserController  that you just hit on
params[:action] -->> contains the action name ex. new or edit
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be done in many ways.

I usually do it like

```
if !@user.new_record?
 # department field.
end
```

Comment: It doesn't work, though I don't get the part new_record? should I have a method in my userController for new_record? or is it some built-in rails method ?

Comment: built-in, `@user` is an AR object

Comment: worked for me. i needed to remove more than a single line, so this is how I chose to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Just put at your form:

```
<%= f.text_field :department unless @user.new_record? %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If params[:action] is edit then do not show that field might be by using display none

Comment: I tried it, but the field is afterwards not shown in both actions, new and edit :(

Comment: But in case of new.. action will be new and not edit then field should be shown. use if else condition show field in case of new action else hide it