# Specify visible input fields from simple_form layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, slim-lang

I'm loading two views that render a simple_form form layout, new and edit.

I need to show all input fields when the user profile is initially being created (new), and specify fields that will not show when it is being used for edit. I've seen a lot of info around `persisted` but can't figure it out.

My `_form.html.slim` file.

```
= simple_form_for([:admin, User.new]) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :name, required: true, label: 'Name'
    = f.input :email, required: true
    = f.input :password, required: true, placeholder: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length)
    = f.input :password_confirmation, required: true

  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit, "Create User", class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg'
```

I'm using Rails and Slim - Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you confused about how to use `persisted?` in your logic?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26817319/4089357

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use `persisted?` to conditionally render the fields in form.

```
= simple_form_for([:admin, User.new]) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :name, required: true, label: 'Name'
    = f.input :email, required: true

    -# Say you don't want user to edit his password after creation
    - unless f.object.persisted?
      = f.input :password, required: true, placeholder: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length)
      = f.input :password_confirmation, required: true

    .form-actions
      = f.button :submit, "Create User", class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg'
```

Here `f.object` will be the `User` instance for which the form will be rendered.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much!